# How to sort in filter without using Dynamic Ranking in Endeca?

Tags: sorting, atg, endeca

We are using Endeca to fetch and display records in frontend as a datagrid. In that datagrid, we have 10 columns and we display data sorted in table on the basis of 2 columns (say X and Y). For this, we use Endeca.stratify(collection()/record[not%20(X)])||X|1||*,Endeca.stratify(collection()/record[not%20(Y)])||Y|1.

We can also apply filter on the columns where we display data sorted asc/desc. We used Dynamic Ranking in Endeca and created dimensions for each field with selecting dynamic ranking and set maximum dimension value to return as 20 as per the requirement. Since we know that dynamic ranking is the relevancy ranking, it fetches most used records and does sorting on that data.

However, we need to select 20 unique values and sort them in asc/desc order. Example: if we have date as the column, then we need to fetch 20 unique dates with most recent at the top. i.e. in descending order.
Is there any other way to do sorting on filter apart from dynamic ranking? If we disable dynamic ranking, then we won't have option to set maximum dimension value as 20 from developer studio.
Please suggest for the ranking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally found a solution!! I removed/unchecked "dynamic ranking" for the properties in dimensions from the pipeline using developer studio. I did not want it to remove since we had already selected an option as sort "alphabetically" instead of "dynamically" in dynamic ranking tab in dimensions.
Also, if we uncheck dynamic ranking then the option for giving maximum limit for displaying the dimensions (which was set 20 for us as per the requirement) was also gone.

So, I handled this in java to display only 20 values by putting a check on results obtained and created a counter which would add values only till the 20 are received. Now this is working as required!!!!!